# nmcli requires password to connect to VPN when nm-applet is not running

Tags: linux, bash, vpn, networkmanager

When I run `nmcli connection up id VPNNAME` when `nm-applet` is not running it requires a password

```
Warnung: Das Passwort für »vpn.secrets.Xauth password« ist nicht in »passwd-file« definiert. nmcli darf nicht ohne die Option »--ask« fragen.
Fehler: Aktivierung der Verbindung ist gescheitert: No valid secrets
```

Translation:

```
Warning: The password for »vpn.secrets.Xauth password« is not defined in »passwd-file«. nmcli cannot ask without the »--ask« option.
Error: Activation of the connection failed: No valid secrets
```

When I add the `--ask` it simply asks for the password to be typed in the terminal.

However, when `nm-applet` is running and I then run `nmcli connection up id VPNNAME` it connects without error or asking for a password.

Is it possible to have it not asking for the password when `nm-applet` is not running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified vpn file found in directory `/etc/NetworkManager` to contain

```
ipSec-secret-type=save
IPSec secret-flags=0
xauth-password-type=save
XAuth password-flags=0
```

and `[vpn-secrets]` section

```
Xauth password=YOUR-PASSWORD    
IPSec secret=IPSEC-PSK
```